# Use process.on('uncaughtException to show a 500 error page

Tags: node.js, error-handling, express

I'm developing an express app.

I currently have the following in my server.js

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.log( "UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION " );
    console.log( "[Inside 'uncaughtException' event] " + err.stack || err.message );
});
```

Which stops the server crashing every time there's an error, however, it just sits there...

is it possible to instead of console.log, to send a 500 error page with the error details?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think you can from within the `uncaughtException` do a response since that could happen even when there is no request occurring.

Express itself provides a way to [handle errors](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#error-handling) within routes, like so:

```
app.error(function(err, req, res, next){
    //check error information and respond accordingly
});
```

Comment: Does not work. `app.error` not defined. Perhaps the ExpressJS API changed since this answer was posted (> 2 years ago). ExpressJS exception handling covered at: http://expressjs.com/guide.html#error-handling

Answer (score 4):

Per [ExpressJS Error Handling](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html), add `app.use(function(err, req, res, next){ // your logic });` below your other `app.use` statements.

Example:

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
  console.log(err.stack);
  // additional logic, like emailing OPS staff w/ stack trace
});
```