# Heroku start stop dyno within app javascript

Tags: node.js, heroku

I want to restart automatically when it get errors.

Currently one worker running but when i get error i need to restart the dyno.

Comment: anything tried so far ?

Comment: i can't imagine anything how can i interrupt worker and restart within index.js

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656859/node-js-with-forever-on-heroku

Answer (score 0):

You could try running the app with [forever js](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever)

Answer (score 0):

Heroku restart your app **just one time** during a period. If the dyno crashes again, it will be subject to a cool-off period before a restart is attempted.

> Documentation: [Dyno crash restart policy of Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#dyno-crash-restart-policy)

If you want to restart your dyno automatically I can suggest you to add an add-on call "Logentries". Then in Logentries create an alert which will be trigger when a crash append (H10 code Heroku). On Logentries you can set a webhook for this alert. And then you can create an another app for restart your app with Heroku API when this webhook is triggered.